# Retrieving all user relations from Parse

Tags: objective-c, object, parse-platform, pfquery

I have an app where users add other users and it is saved as a relation on Parse. Here is the code I use to save it/add:

```
    PFUser *user = (PFUser *)object;
    [friendsRelation addObject:user];
    [self.friends addObject:user];
    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@" %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

Now, in another view controller, I don't really know how I would do to display all of the friends of a user within a `TableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using `PFQueryTableViewController`.This allows you to query the relation and display the results in a table. The code for that would look something like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table
        NSLog(@"Init");
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"_User";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"firstName";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = NO;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 25;
    }
    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {


    PFQuery *query = [self.relation query];




    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {

        NSLog(@"NONE");
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyIgnoreCache;

    }

    [query orderByAscending:@"lastName"];

    return query;
}
```

Where `self.relation`is the relation that you grab from the current user.

EDITL If you do not wish to use PFQTVC (it's the easier option, and contains more features), you can just use a regular tableview. First, get the relation from your current user:

`PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"friends"];`
Now, query this relation:

```
PFQuery *query = [relation query];
NSArray *array = [query findObjects];
```

Now you can fill your regular table with the contents of that array, which contains PFUser objects.

Comment: This line's not working `PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"friends"];` Can I just use `PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];`

Comment: That was just an example, I don't know what your actual schema is, you have to fill in your columns

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed that. But how would I set the username of the friend as a text? In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have `cell.username.text = (array??);`

Comment: array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row; that would be to retrieve the PFUser for that spot, then just get the info from there that you need

Comment: Listen, I'm not writing your entire app for you. I think you need to take a look at the parse docs and read up on objects and how to retrieve data from them.

Comment: Good job! Just get rid of that if statement, and keep the code inside it and it will work for every cell! Please mark my answer as correct and maybe up vote if I helped you ;)

Comment: Okay, but if I do that, I can't set up the button table view cell under it.

Comment: Why don't you set the table footer as the button, then you won't have to add an extra cell.

Comment: Is there a way to make a footer from storyboard?

Comment: Because it seems I already did that by dropping two table view cells onto the table view controller in storyboard

Comment: You can just drag a button below the tableview on your storyboard. This is getting off topic, ask a new question if you need more help.